# How to get the structure members from a TagDecl with clang

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I have an AST consumer that get all the TagDecl which are structure with

```
clang::TagDecl::isStruct()
```

How to get members of the structure (declaration, type) in an array like the FunctionDecl class:

```
clang::FunctionDecl::getParamDecl(unsigned i)
```

Or in any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TagDecl` must be cast to a `RecordDecl` that have the methods to get the members / fields information.

```
clang::TagDecl*t;
clang::RecordDecl*r;
clang::RecordDecl::field_iterator jt;

for(jt = r->field_begin(); jt != r->field_end();++jt)
{
    std::cout << jt->getType().getAsString() << " " << jt->getNameAsString() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void HandleTagDeclDefinition(TagDecl *D) override
{    
    if(D->isStruct())
    {    
        DeclContext *DC = static_cast<DeclContext *>(D);
        for (DeclContext::decl_iterator DI = DC->decls_begin(), DEnd = DC->decls_end();
            DI != DEnd; ++DI) 
        {
            DI->dump();
        }
    }
}
```

**You should add this function to the class which you extend to ASTConsumer.**

> Storage of declarations within that context
>
> Every declaration context can contain some number of declarations. For
>   example, a C++ class (represented by RecordDecl) contains various
>   member functions, fields, nested types, and so on. All of these
>   declarations will be stored within the DeclContext, and one can
>   iterate over the declarations via [DeclContext::decls_begin(),
>   DeclContext::decls_end()). This mechanism provides the source-centric
>   view of declarations in the context.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping a code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.